# Loading from Google Cloud Storage backup in one project to BigQuery in another project

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two projects in Google Cloud and I want to load entities from both projects into one BigQuery dataset using backups. BigQuery loads from backup in the same project, and my problem is that I also need to load from backup located in the other project. The sample https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatagcs shows that there is job reference project (the project that contains the backup in its storage) and also `configuration.load.destinationTable.projectId` (the BigQuery project). It runs but it looks like it doesn't have effect.

Is it possible to load from backup located in other project?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using Service Account that has permissions in both projects.